# Checking particular button from many

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a form in which I have 3 buttons - Make Payment, Cancel and Print.

All of these buttons except cancel(it resets) when clicked, the data flows through a POST method to a same function in another file. In this function I am trying to segregate the outputs using the following code :

```
function emp_sal_in($data)
{
    $msg = '';
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { //something posted
        if (isset($_POST['Print'])) {
            $msg = 'This is printing the data';
            return $msg;
        } else {
            if ($this->db->insert('employeesalarypayment', $data)) {
                $msg = '<p class="bg-success">Employee Salary Details Recorded successfully....</p>';
            } else {
                $msg = '<p class="bg-danger">Problem Occured</p>';
            }

            return $msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my buttons HTML code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-label-left">
            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
            Make Payment
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-1">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-label-left">
            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-label-left">
            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
            Print
        </button>
    </div>                                          
</div>
```

But it always executes the else part. Even if I click Print. Please guide me. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You need to give them `name="Print"` `and name="Make Payment"` to test the value on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set button `name` & `value` attributes, so that `$_POST` has the key with name of button and its value in it.

```
<button type="submit" name="print_btn" value="print">Print</button>
```

and, then check for 'print_btn' key in `$_POST`

```
if (isset($_POST['print_btn']) && $_POST['print_btn'] == "print") {

    //your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have any input element with name "Print"

You must have some input element like following:

You can check your posted data by print `$_POST` array like:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
```

It will print values posted from your form in a nice way and you can check which indexes are set in it.